# Why ask research level questions?

Tags: discussion

When you ask a research level question, don't you expect a research level answer.  Why would I ask a question that I could answer from a standard text?

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: @Manishearth He's probably talking about http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/60150/is-the-spectral-pattern-for-hydrogen-related-to-how-the-sun-bends-or-gravitation

Comment: @dmckee:  It is really not about this specific question because all the questions I asked I can answer.  It is really about a certain level of professionalism that you did not show when you attempted to insult me.  I would gladly put my research up against anything you have ever done and that is not an insult that is a fact.

Comment: @user4884: I don't see any attempted insult. Your question isn't about mainstream physics -- it seems to be about your own "research". We won't do your research for you here; that's not what this site is for.

Comment: @user4884:  Engineering is mainstream physics and I did not ask anyone to do any research for me.  My research is already published in a peer-reviewed journal, conference and reported.  dmckee statement is an attempted insult with respect to my work and anyone else who does real science (Engineering) not multiple universes.

Comment: @user4884: So...you have published papers about the connection between the spectral pattern and lensing? If so, then there was no need to ask the question. If not, then the question isn't mainstream physics.

Comment: @Manishearth:  I published a paper on how harmonic structures are synchronized within the geometry of spatially extending point objects.  Synchronizing the electromagnetic and gravitational field of binary stars confirmed my research which was not links between lensing and spectral patterns.  Everyone is asking research level questions for different reasons and giving answers for different reasons.  Mainstream science has nothing to do with that.  If you can't test it, it's not mainstream science.

Comment: @user4884 Bottom line: if you have a conceptual question about a well-established theory, you can ask that. For a niche topic like a link between gravity and the hydrogen spectrum, you would have to cite peer-reviewed research to demonstrate that the theory is well established, and to provide potential answerers with reading material to understand it. Otherwise, your question is off topic. That's all I'm going to say on the matter.

Comment: @David Zaslawsky: I really don't remember having time to do any of what you are talking about because I was defending myself against a moderator's unprofessional behavior which I can assume by the responses it is not only tolerated but condoned.  Research is about the limits of theory and how to test those limits.  Publishing in a science and technology journal is not like publishing in a mathematical physics journal.  No facts, no test, no publication:  That's the rules.  I don't cite unrested theories, I cited observational publications.

Comment: @user4884:  "research level":  I do not think these words mean what you think they mean.

Comment: I deleted some off topic comments.

Comment: @David Zaslavsky:  Why is dmckee's first statement not off topic, he has no right to speculate on my reasons for asking this question, divert the answers to a place that has generated these down votes.  I guess a moderator's statements are always on topic even when they are not.  This is a case. I speak for me not dmckee.

Comment: Reputable journals are peer-reviewed so I guess arXiv documents should also be excluded because the majority are not peer-reviewed.  Based on the logic of the undeleted answer.

Comment: You have to be able to standardize the definition of an orbit to complete my research which includes the question dmckee closed. If can't answer that question why would I come to the cite to have my research expanded.  Where is the logic of the undeleted answer?

Comment: Last, Manishearth did not even know the content of the closed question was in a peer-review publication when he answered the "question" out of ignorance.  Quick to comment, slow to read.

Comment: Manishearth evokes Maldacena's Ads/CFT theory as an example of mainstream physics.  Maldacena wins the Fundamental Physics Prize for trying to do what I did.  Ads/CFT would never get published in a science and technology journal.  Not data, no test, no publication.  That's the rule.  A real quantum association with gravity has to make some testable predictions and solve some outstanding problems in Astronomy of which there are many.  Ads/CFT does none of that but it is mainstream.  Really.

Comment: @user4884: This is more of trolling than anything else . It makes testable predictions . If you don't know string theory, please don't criticise it baselessly . "Mainstream" doesn't equal "Testable" , besides . The theory  that                     I will rule the world in 2 minutes is testable, but it isn't mainstream . Sure, to be mainstream, it must be testable, but not vice versa . I haven't seen the question, but your  comments here make it seem that it was utter . . . One of [these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Dimension10/Nonsense#._Complete_Nonsense_kinds_of_quack)

Comment: You cited a link in the discussion between you and Manishearth in chat. That link has *absolutely nothing* to do with    quantum systems  intereact with 2                             gravity, etc . (P.S. Unlike what you say in the description of your other account,  (which also particuipated in the chat discussion, .)                                                                                 even if that "theory" of yours, were     really senseible,  that wouldn't be quantum gravity. c.f.   (contd.)

Comment: (contd.) http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/57799/why-isnt-the-bekenstein-hawking-entropy-considered-the-quantum-gravitational-un       .     )  PLUS you said, that "And for the record. During my peer-review process a number of String Theorist were angry because they were not cited in my paper. What mathematician cites a conjecture to establish a proof? You prove conjecture you don't make it the argument." . If the reviewer  EXPLICITLY says "YOU FOOL!, CITE ME!!!", it probably isn't a reliable, journal .  AND, string theory isn't a "conjecture". Stop lashing out at mainstream (Contd.)

Comment: (Contd.) theories to support your own  non-mainstream ideas you advertise . AND, if you think that    your paper is mainstream and accepted, then "WHY ask a question about it?".  It seems to me that you're just promoting your non-mainstream ideas here   .        AND saying that reviewers told you to cite them is by no way an argument for you .   "If I can google, why ask a question?" Because Google/Yahoo/ Bing/user4884SEARCH did not yield a result? Because you can't find a text - book ? Because it can't be found in a standard text (this is the real definition. of research-level, actua (contd.)

Comment: (contd.)  lly, not promotion of non-mainstream "Research".)        You say that dmckee's comments are "off-topic", but his comments are pertaining to the EXACT same question, you're talking about, and are certainly NOT an insult .   " People make fatal comments about paper the do not have time to read" Example  ? . "Citation inflation is unethical." No, it happens when the paper isn't crackpot (though in some cases, when it is amusingly crackpot, but that's irrgrelevant, here . , . , ,  . ). And whether an ArXiV papeer is mainstream or not   , is judged by "citation inflation", in your terms .

Answer (score 5):

I don't really see what you mean here. (Assuming you're talking about https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/60150/is-the-spectral-pattern-for-hydrogen-related-to-how-the-sun-bends-or-gravitation#question)

Quoting the [FAQ](https://physics.stackexchange.com/faq):

> We deal with mainstream physics here. Anything that couldn't be published in a reputable journal is probably not appropriate at this site.

On this site, we ask and answer questions about established physics. "According to X theory, how does Y work?" is OK. "I have theory X, is it correct?" is not OK. We don't *do* research here; we only give information on established physics.

Your question is more or less of that form (this is made clearer by seeing the comments) where you have a theory and you want the site to expand/validate it. That's not what Physics.SE is for :s

Comment: My research was published in a reputable journal and at a applied engineering conference.

Comment: @user4884: Links? If your research on this was already published, why did you need to ask the question?

Comment: If I can google an answer why ask a question?

Comment: @user4884: Please provide precise reference.

Comment: I deleted some off topic comments.

Comment: @Manishearch:  Why does a teacher ask students questions when they already "know" the answer?  It is not about the question it is about thinking and the answers says more about the student then the question.  Research level questions are suppose to make you thing.

Comment: Everyone responding to this question thinks it is about the physics stack exchange when it is really about the physics community,  the physics stack exchange is not the whole physics community.  It is just part of a larger community which will have to answer this question from a student's perspective.  Not as a teacher who "knows".

Comment: @user4884: You still have not supplied us with _any_ links to your so-called "mainstream" paper. I really don't think that the conversation can proceed productively without that. It's not that physics.SE contains all parts of the physics community -- it is that we don't allow all sorts of questions contained in the physics community. Your postdoc adviser may give you some research questions. That doesn't mean that they are appropriate here.

Comment: @Manishearch:  This question is not about my paper and I don't have a postdoc advisor.  The link to my paper is on my profile website, which is where my paper was reported on in Anne Astronomy News.

Comment: @user4884: ...then you cannot say that the question is about mainstream physics. We don't care if you have published a paper. Does your question have a fair amount of mainstream backing?

Comment: And the postdoc adviser thing was just a general statement, not meant to apply to you.

Comment: What do you mean "does my question have a fair amount of mainstream backing?"  Do  you mean does my research have a fair amount of mainstream backing?

Comment: @user4884: See, most question on Physics.SE are _about_ established mainstream theories. For example, AdS/CFT is an established mainstream theory -- there are papers on this, and questions about the theory are fine. However, your question more or less proposes new physics. We really don't deal with that kind of stuff here. If your question linked to a paper proposing this same new physics and asked for an explanation, that would be fine. If you had a confusion regarding nuances of this new theory, that would also be fine as long as you had mainstream backing. But you don't :/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8225/discussion-between-user4884-and-manishearth)

Comment: We must remember that empirically established theories and citation established theories not the same.  My research is empirically established, most citation established theories have no evidence just a crowd saying "you right, you right"  That's not evidence.

Comment: Both these papers http://arxiv.org/abs/1111.3328 and
http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2010AAS...21541934Z  confirm the conclusions reached in my paper. And these are not fellow researchers with a financial interest in citing my conclusions as a group.  That is empirically established mainstream.  We point to results and not people to say "you're right".  Both papers were the subject of Nature publications.

Comment: Neither paper talks about the relation between lensing and spectra. You still have not provided a _single_ mainstream reference that is about that.

Comment: This is not an exclusive conversation.  The first paper confirms the existence of wave functions and a real wave function cannot be constructed on an orbit without an enter space which has a hydrogen spatial configuration and that analysis was used to synchronize a gravitational and electromagnetic field which ultimately cracked the DI Heruclis problem.  That is the subject of the second paper.

Comment: @mcDee You deleted facts:  The question is “Why ask research level questions?” not lets evaluate a statement made on another form. My research statements are mathematically correct and experimentally confirmed which are the only two references real science requires from real scientist. My research was published in a science and technology journal because I met those peer reviewed requirements. My research was also presented at an international applied physics or engineering conference for the same reason. Anne Astronomy News reported my findings to the laymen astronomy community.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8258/discussion-between-user4884-and-manishearth)